# atexit for singleton destruction : failure case

Tags: c++, static, singleton, destructor, atexit

From : https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/to_kill_a_singleton

> One thing's for sure: you can't use more than one destroyer if the
>   singleton destructors depend on one another. An alternative is to
>   eschew destroyers altogether and rely instead on the draft-standard
>   atexit() function, as Tim Peierls suggested to me: I maintain that
>   atexit() is a good way to cleanup singletons in C++ when you really
>   want single instances with program lifetime and no replacement.
>
> The draft standard promises a lot: The function atexit() from can be
>   used to specify a function to be called at exit. If atexit() is to be
>   called, the implementation shall not destroy objects initialized
>   before an atexit() call until after the function specified in the
>   atexit() call has been called.
>
> The only way I can see this failing is if a statically initialized
>   object whose destructor depends on a Singleton instance is initialized
>   *after* the Singleton instance is constructed, i.e., through some other static initialization. This suggests that classes having static
>   instances should avoid depending on singletons during destruction. (Or
>   at least there should be a way for such classes to check for the
>   existence of the Singleton during destruction.)

I couldn't understand the last paragraph i.e. in which case it will fail and how.

Could someone please throw some light on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this uses `atexit` instead of destructors to clean up the Singletons, the order of object cleanup can be changed.  For example:

```
Singleton S;
Object O;
// later in code:
Call atexit() to register cleanup function for S
```

Normally the destruction order for these objects will be O then S, but with the `atexit` call added this is reversed, so that S is cleaned up in the `atexit` call, then O is destroyed.  If O's destructor depends in any way on the Singleton S you'll have undefined behavior while that destructor is running.

The way to avoid that is to call `atexit` to register the Singleton cleanup function before constructing any objects that depend on it.  If O is itself a static object, this can be tricky and may require creating a class whose constructor calls `atexit` so it can be inserted between the two static objects.

```
Singleton S;
struct SAtExit {
     SAtExit() { atexit(...); }
} SCleanup;
Object O;
```